# Rails : Application Error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I successfully deployed my app to heroku then did `heroku open` I got `Application Error` on my web page. I did `heroku restart` and tried but didn't work. I did heroku logs and heroku run rails console but still confused what error I got for. Below is what I am lookig to find error.

> 2016-09-16T14:06:10.615311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 29036 -e production`
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802759+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802787+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:29036
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802788+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802788+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802789+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802793+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Cannot load`Rails.application.database_configuration`: (Psych::BadAlias)
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802793+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown alias: default
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in`fetch'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`visit'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802796+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802796+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802796+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:338:in `block in revive_hash'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802797+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802797+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in `each_slice'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`revive_hash'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:162:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`visit'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:338:in `block in revive_hash'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in `each_slice'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`revive_hash'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:162:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`visit'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:311:in`visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in `visit'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in`accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in `accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802806+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:253:in`load'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802813+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:104:in `database_configuration'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802806+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:38:in`to_ruby'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802814+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`accept'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802815+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802815+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`execute_hook'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802816+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802816+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802816+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802817+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in`'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802818+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802818+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802821+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802822+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802844+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:121:in`'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:1:in`'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802846+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802846+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802848+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802848+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `block in eager_load!'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802849+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in`each_value'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802849+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record.rb:160:in `eager_load!'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802849+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in`eager_load!'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in`block in '
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802854+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802855+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in`block in tsort_each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802857+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802869+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802870+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802870+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802870+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802884+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each_strongly_connected_component'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802885+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802885+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in`tsort_each'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802885+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802887+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`initialize!'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802888+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in`require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`instance_eval'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802892+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802893+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in`new'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802894+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802895+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`eval'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802897+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802909+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`parse_file'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802910+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802910+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in`app'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802913+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802915+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in`wrapped_app'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802916+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802916+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in`start'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802916+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802917+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802931+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802932+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in`require'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.802935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `'
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.872751+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2016-09-16T14:06:13.872732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   2016-09-16T15:29:42.219103+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-mountain-58433.herokuapp.com request_id=555caccd-f3cb-41c0-9e1e-ff9b44b26cd0 fwd="124.219.169.191" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> and below is heroku run rails console
>
> /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Cannot load`Rails.application.database_configuration`: (Psych::BadAlias)
>   Unknown alias: default
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in`fetch'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`visit'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:338:in `block in revive_hash'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`each'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in `each_slice'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`revive_hash'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:162:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`visit'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:338:in `block in revive_hash'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`each'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in `each_slice'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:336:in`revive_hash'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:162:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`visit'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:311:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in`visit'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in`accept'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:38:in `to_ruby'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:253:in`load'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:104:in `database_configuration'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in`block (2 levels) in '
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`execute_hook'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`each'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in`'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:121:in`'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:1:in`'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `block in eager_load!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in`each_value'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `eager_load!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record.rb:160:in`eager_load!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in`block in '
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in`block in tsort_each'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in`tsort_each'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`initialize!'
>       from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in`require'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in`require_application_and_environment!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /app/bin/rails:9:in`require'
>       from /app/bin/rails:9:in `'

Comment: From above, code called H10 is the reason why I got error for but still concern what I should have done.

Comment: How does your `database.yml` file look like?

Comment: plus one for @Vasile 's comment.  Your app/config/database.yml is likely badly formatted.

Comment: Please check out the below I posted what you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

This `database.yml` should work for you

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 pool: 5

development:
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  database: db/test.sqlite3
```

But I would advise agains using a different database adapter for development.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vasile. I did what you suggested then I got new error which said "Internal Server Error
Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`"

Comment: Open the `secrets.yml` file and check if there are any environment variables used,  I think it's probably `SECRET_KEY_BASE` that needs to be put in your Heroku settings. Or run  `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE="some secret key"`. You  can generate a secure  token with `rake secret`.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. If you got the problem sorted, would you mind selecting my answer as the right one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
production:
 <<: *default
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 pool: 5


development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3
```

Above is my database.yml. Are there anything wrong?

Comment: oh I noticed that I can't run 'heroku rake db:migrate'. Is this related to this issue? How can I make this command work?

Comment: Do you have a `default` block as well?

Comment: I do not see any information that Heroky provides such as Server, User and password.